# Is border-image possible in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to incorporate the border-image property into a project using Tailwind [arbitrary syntax](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties), but my styles aren't being applied. Am I missing something? Is this even possible with Tailwind? Thanks!

My code:

`<button className="[border-image:linear-gradient(to top right, #f6b73c, #4d9f0c) 30] border-4 border-solid border-transparent bg-white p-4"> Hello! </button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something and it is possible with Tailwind. Consider removing any optional spaces within the arbitrary property class and escaping essential spaces with underscore (`_`). This is needed since the space character delimits class names.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<button class="[border-image:linear-gradient(to_top_right,#f6b73c,#4d9f0c)_30] border-4 border-solid border-transparent bg-white p-4"> Hello! </button>
```

Comment: Ah yes! I keep forgetting that one needs to add underscores to specify a space with arbitrary syntax.